# How to convert MMMM dd, yyyy into MM/dd/yyyy format

Tags: c#, asp.net

How i convert `MMMM dd, yyyy` into any format.
I have `November 6, 2010`. How i convert it into `MM/dd/yyyy` like `02/06/2014` format.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

where `dt` is your datetime.

Comment: The result of this _can_ be change based on OP's `CurrentCulture`. Using a culture which has `DateSeparator` as a `/` character (like `InvariantCulture`) as a second parameter in your `ToString()` method can solve this.

Comment: @SonerGönül thank you very much ! I corrected my answer.